# MYSQL : How to retrieve a certain Value of a variable value?

Tags: mysql

i have a question with regard to a complicated query. So the task is the following:

```
With which connections can or could one fly from Düsseldorf (ICAO_Code : EDDF)  
to Rome (ICAO_Code: LIRA), whereby a travel time of 24 hours should not be 
exceeded,
you are allowed to change trains for a maximum of 1 hour and have a minimum 
transfer time of 1 hour?
```

The tables look like this:

```
**flightexecution** (FlightNo, DepartureDateAndTimeUTC, ICAO_Origin, 
ICAO_Destination, PlaneID, FlightDurationInMinutes)
```

and

```
**airport** (ICAO_Code, AirportName, Address,ID)
```

My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT fe.ICAO_Code_Origin, 
    CASE
    WHEN fe.ICAO_Code_Origin = 'EDDF' AND fe.ICAO_Code_Destination = 'LIRA' 
    THEN 'DIREKTFLUG' 
    ELSE fe.ICAO_Code_Destination 
    AS via,
    CASE
    WHEN fe.ICAO_Code_Origin = 'EDDF' AND fe.ICAO_Code_Destination = 'LIRA'
    THEN 0
    ELSE DATEDIFF(min, , SELEC....
```

The last statement is the problematic one. I want to say: "Time difference between the (DepartureDateAndTime of the intermediate stop) - (DepartureDateAndTime + FlightDurationInMinutes).

But how do i tell MYSQL that i want this specific ICAO_Origin?

Comment: Not train information. Not suare what you are trying to achieve with "Time difference...". Do you have some sample data and expected results? What MySQL/MariaDB version? Later versions have recursive CTEs which might be required depending on how you clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

```
SELECT FlightNo,...
FROM flightexecution fe
WHERE fe.ICAO_Code_Origin = 'EDDF'
  AND fe.ICAO_Code_Destination = 'LIRA'
  AND FlightDurationInMinutes < 24*60;
```

Insufficient information on trains is provided to answer that alternate.